# Запятая перед "с применением"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая в предложении: "...приготовление основы из масла, другого сырья (,) с применением или без применения различных ароматических добавок".
Приготовление (из чего?) из масла, (из чего?) из сырья, (как?) с применением... Вроде не нужно ставить запятую (или все-таки нужно?), а поставить хочется.

Answer (score 1):

**Возможны оба варианта**, также союз ИЛИ, как мне кажется, надо добавить:

1)"...приготовление основы из масла или другого сырья с применением или без применения различных ароматических добавок". Здесь **неоднородные** члены предложения обозначают разные признаки (из чего и как).

2) "...приготовление основы из масла или другого сырья, с применением или без применения различных ароматических добавок". Здесь **однородные члены предложения обозначают сближенные признаки** (обозначаются различные варианты основы, м**ожно подобрать обобщающее слово**: "...приготовление основы различными способами: из масла или другого сырья, с применением или без применения различных ароматических добавок".